# Mock a return value for a private method that has been marked as accessible

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, private-methods

My unit test:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
  Method m = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("methodToBeMocked");
  m.setAccessible(true); 
  MyClass myClass = spy(new MyClass());
  //m.invoke(myClass); // Calling this invokes the private method correctly

  when(myClass.methodToBeMocked()).thenReturn("DummyReturn"); // This line throws the compiler error

  myClass.doSomething(); // This is the method I'm trying to test
}
```

This is the compiler error I get:

```
The method methodToBeMocked() from the type MyClass is not visible
```

This is `MyClass`

```
public MyClass {

  public MyClass() {}

  public void doSomething() {
    ..
    methodToBeMocked();
    ..
  }

  private String methodToBeMocked() { // Need to mock return value
    return "Default";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explanatory.

> The method methodToBeMocked() from the type MyClass is not visible

The reason the method isn't visible is because it is a `private` method. Private methods can only be called within the class they are defined. If you want the method to be accessible from anywhere, make the method `public`.

```java
public String methodToBeMocked() { // Need to mock return value
    return "Default";
  }
```

[Information about method access specifiers](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodaccess.html)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid making the method `public`? Without the use of powermock

Comment: You can make the method `protected` if the test class is in the same package as MyClass. Or you can move the test method into MyClass.